# Replace multiple hex values

Tags: perl, file, replace, sed, hex

I've written the following script because I need to do some cleanup in some files. I have a specific number of hex characters that needs to be changed into another set of hex characters (ie null to space, see below). I've written the following script, my problem is that it only replaces the first occurence and nothing else.

I've tried the /g just like a regular sed pattern but it doesnt work. Is there a way to do this and replace all matches?

(The reason i havent used a `$line =~ s/...` is because I think its neater and more maintainable that way, and this script will need to be accessed and run on occasion by others who may need to edit the hex values to be replaced). Another reason is because i need to change from 10+ hex values to an equivalent amount, so a huge one liner would be hard to read. Thank you in advance.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl


 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $filebase = shift || "testreplace.txt";
 my $filefilter = shift || "testf";

 open my $fh1, '>', 'testreplaceout';

 # Iterate over file and read lines
 open my $file1, '<', $filebase;

 while (my $line = <$file1>)
 {
    chomp($line);

    for ($line) {
            s/\x00/\x20/g;
            s/\x31/\x32/g;
    }

    print {$fh1} "$line \n";


 }
```

Comment: I think when replacing exactly one character with exactly one other character, `tr` would be better (faster), i.e. `$line =~ tr/\x00/\x20/;` (no `/g`).

Comment: I m going to try it, the files are huge so i ll compare times and let you know! Thanks for the suggestion. I dont remember off the top of my head but i think tr can also replace a range of characters with one specific one, in the spirit of tr /\x00-x20/\x20/;

Comment: tr is a good suggestion.  A single tr can translate as many characters as you want.  e.g. `tr/abc/xyz/` will change a to x, b to y, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update: read comments for caveats of this answer.

Here's one way that'll allow you to keep your list of regex search/replaces at the top of your script nice and clean for ease of viewing and modification:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @re_list = (
    ['a', 'x'],
    ['b', 'y'],
);

while (my $line = <DATA>){
    for my $re (@re_list){
        $line =~ s/$re->[0]/$re->[1]/g;
    }
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
aaabbbccc
bbbcccddd
ababababa
```

Output:

```
xxxyyyccc
yyycccddd
xyxyxyxyx
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it can't handle `['a', 'x'], ['x', 'y']`

Answer (score 0):

`/g` will do what you want.  If it doesn't seem to be working, add some debugging:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
```

And in your loop:

```
print Dumper($line);
for ($line) {
        s/\x00/\x20/g;
        s/\x31/\x32/g;
}
print Dumper($line);
```

Using tr with paired delimiters instead can be very readable/maintainable:

```
$line =~ tr[\x00\x31]
                  [\x20\x32];
```

Also, consider adding `use autodie;`

Answer (score 0):

`tr///` is probably your best bet here (since you are dealing with constant single character replacements). The following is a more generic solution.

```
my %replacements = (
   'foo' => 'bar',
   'bar' => 'baz',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%replacement);

s/($pat)/$replacements{$1}/g;
```